# Can't bypass or ignore Default Error pages in IIS/.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, iis, error-handling

I am working on a VB .NET application, In my code I use a **Try Catch** to Catch a *"File unavailable / Already in use"* exception and then redirect to a "Please wait" page.

```
Try
   //DB connection
   //Queries
Catch ex As System.Exception
     Response.Redirect("BlockZ1E.aspx")
Finally
     MyConnection.Close()
End Try
```

The *Try Catch* does work, It caught's the exception when the file is unavailable and redirects to the Please Wait page, if the file is available it works fine.
The thing is, it only works locally, when I try running the application on a server **(Windows Server 2016, IIS 10.0)** my code never catches the exception because the default/standard error pages from IIS (Yellow Screen of Death) or .NET always appears first with the "File already in use" exception. I need different kinds of Error Pages, so creating a Custom Error (from IIS Manager or web.config file) doesn't work for me. Again, if the file is available, then everything goes fine, even on the server.

I've tried Bypassing or Turning Off the Default Error Pages with different things like TrySkipIisCustomErrors and web.config options, tried with:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true
```

And

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
```

And

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough />
```

None of those worked for me.

Any kind of help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: And what settings have you in relation to the `<customErrors>` tag in the config of the live site? https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/815166/how-to-troubleshoot-asp-net-web-applications

Comment: And does th stacktrace indicate your code is crashing somewhere outside the try?

Comment: Ensure that **before each error output generation** you add bypass IIS Custom Error settings:`Context.Server.ClearErrors()
Context.Response.IisTrySkipIisCustomErrors` and `<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Passthrough" />
</system.webServer>`

Comment: @CaiusJard The file that sometimes is "Unavailable" is a .ldb file, that comes and goes, for that reason the stacktrace just shows the line the when exception occurred(file became unavailable), but it is always a different line, and it is always inside the try catch. (It sounds as if the Try Catch wasn't working, but it does work when it's running local)
As for the  **<cutomErrors>** settings, I've tried **mode=On/Off** and **On** with **defaultRedirect**

Comment: LDB as in the file that Microsoft access uses to manage concurrent access to an MDB?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, that kind of file

Comment: Why would you want to serve that file over http?